# add a annotation to a PDF with PDFBOX then overlay another PDF on line 2

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I have to create a one line annotation on top of an existing PDF with PDFBOX. It has to be in the upper right hand corner of the existing PDF. Most of the time, there is space there to append the line in the existing PDF. Sometimes there is a stamp in the right hand corner that prohibits me from putting the annotation there. The best I have been able to do is write a new page with the annotation on top, then merge the 2 PDFs together. Annotation code:

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;  
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
public class Document_Creation {

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

  //Creating PDF document object 
  PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
  PDPage page = new PDPage();
  document.addPage(page);
  //Retrieving the pages of the document 
  PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true);

  //Begin the Content stream 
  contentStream.beginText(); 

  //Setting the font to the Content stream  
  contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD, 8);

  //Setting the position for the line 
  contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 775);

  String text = args[1];

  //Adding text in the form of string 
  contentStream.showText(text);      

  //Ending the content stream
  contentStream.endText();

  System.out.println("Content added best friend");

  //Closing the content stream
  contentStream.close();

  //Saving the document
  document.save(args[0]);

  //Closing the document  
  document.close();
```

Comment: So what is your question :)

Comment: How do I create a PDF with just one line of text instead of a whole page with one line of text on top, and then merge an existing PDF to line number 2?

Comment: *"How do I create a PDF with just one line of text instead of a whole page with one line of text on top"* - if you *create a PDF with just one line of text*, that text is **always** on some page. Where else should it be?

Comment: Sorry, I get a complete page with one line of text and the rest of it blank. I need to then overlay my existing PDF on line 2 of the previous page I just created.  I have played with things like the overlay class, but not with any success. Less than one month of experience with java.

Comment: So you're asking how to create a page that is small? Why didn''t you say so in the title? See the PDPage constructor javadoc.

Comment: I get one hit when I google PDPage +Javadoc.  Is Javadoc  part of PDFBOX or is it an Oracle product? If I just google Javadoc, I get hits with Oracle. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I have never worked manipulating PDFs or JAVA before. So I tried to form my question the best I could based on my limited amount of knowledge. I apologize for any confusion I created. I am grateful for any assistance anyone can offer.

Comment: "Javadoc" is the description format for java. I don't know about other IDEs, but in Netbeans you get it when clicking STRG-SPACE. The PDPage javadoc can be found here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.html The whole javadoc is here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/ . So `new PDPage(PDRectangle.A6)` might help you.

Comment: If you want to create a custom sized page, be aware that the dimensions are not pixels but 1/72 inches. 1 inch = 2.52 cm.

Comment: If you need further advice from somebody in the comments, please start the comment with "@" and then the name. Some people even get an alert on their mobiles if they have the app installed.

Comment: Can someone give me a JAVA code example of how to create a PDF using PDFBOX that is a half inch in size vertically?  I have researched and tried to apply JAVA examples for hours without any success. Thanks.

Comment: PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(PDRectangle.A4.getWidth(), 72 / 2));
        doc.addPage(page);
        doc.save("halfinch.pdf");

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It puts the line in the middle of the page using your code, not the top. Also researched this, could not find what 72/2 dimension means for the float height. Thanks.

Comment: Try a number between 0 and 36-fontheight for your text. In PDF, y=0 is bottom. 1 unit = 1/72 inch. Thus, 36 units = 36/72 inch = 1/2 inch.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sorry do not know what you mean by this: "Try a number between 0 and 36-fontheight for your text. In PDF, y=0 is bottom." Are these 2 statements related? Do you mean when a write a line of text, it will change the actual position? I am just executing your code, which gives me white space in the middle.

Comment: Re "white space in the middle", you asked for a PDF with a small height. My code creates that. Re "between 0 and 36", I meant that to write on that small page, instead of `contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 775);` replace 775 with a different number, e.g. 28 (36 - 8). Because the page is only 36 units high and your font is 8pt high. "y=0 is bottom" means that unlike java, in PDF vertical (y) coordinate 0 is the bottom of the page, not the top.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr. Did not know you were referring to my code in this post. So now, I have a smaller cover page with my annotation, then the PDF that I want to annotate starting on page 2. When I wanted them both on page 1. Which takes me back to my original question.   "How do I create a PDF with just one line of text instead of a whole page with one line of text on top, and then merge an existing PDF to line number 2?"  I am using PDFmerger.mergeDocuments. I guess I need to do something else to get page 1 of my PDF to overlay the annotation page.. I tried Overlay with no success.

Comment: Make your life simple: you don't have to use overlay or merge here. You can add the page to an existing PDF with `addPage()`. The parameter would be the PDPage created with my code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  This adds the new small page to the bottom of the existing PDF.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? If not, what did you want?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Back to my first question again at the beginning of the comments. Want the annotation on top. And also the annotation and page one being merged as one page.

Comment: Then all you'd have to do is that `page`, instead of being created with `new PDPage()`, open the existing document with `PDDocument.load(file)` and then call `getPage(0)` to get that page. Then use the code that is in your question. This will append a extra content to the existing one.

Comment: Your initial question mentioned "Sometimes there is a stamp in the right hand corner that prohibits me from putting the annotation there" and "The best I have been able to do is write a new page with the annotation on top, then merge the 2 PDFs together" so I thought you wanted to append a 2nd page.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr No. As you pointed out from my explanation, what I started all this was page 1 being just an annotation, page 2 being the beginning of the PDF. I need these 2 to co-exist on page 1. With the annotation being on the top.

Comment: If you want the text to be on top, then do what I mentioned in the comment that tells to use `new PDPage()`. This will put the text on top of the existing page. (You may have to adjust the 775 to something like `page.getCropBox().getHeight() - 20` so that it works with different page sizes)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  Thanks for the time you have spent helping. I guess the best I am going to be able to do with my month of JAVA experience is to just overlay the annotation over the existing text when it is there. The state of PA will not allow a new page with the annotation text, which is what I started and ended with. Really not sure where to start with the suggestion you gave. Just got to go forward with what I can get to work. Have spent countless hours looking and trying examples to make this work. My face is sore from hitting the wall.

Comment: There's probably some communication problem between you and me... hopefully som trivial misunderstanding... maybe keep this question with all the comments, and focus on a single problem, maybe even ask a new question and link to some PDF you want to change, implement some code, and explain what you got and what you wanted instead. Btw, "annotation" is something specific in PDFs, from your code I assume you wanted ordinary text. You can also ask questions in the user mailing list, that is less formal.